# Simple groups and subroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group of order $d! \leq |G| < \infty$ which is simple, that is, every group homomorphism $\pi : G \to K$ is either injective or $im \; \pi = \{e\}$. Show that $G$ has no subgroup $H$ with $|G|/|H| = d$

Comment: Think about the action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$...

Comment: Thank you @Hempelicious